# Accessing Google Calendar API with OAUTH2 via Perl

Tags: json, perl, google-api

I've been trying to authenticate with a google calendar with a service account, and not having much luck.  The following program dies during the JSON::WebToken encode call with

RSA.xs:178: OpenSSL error: bad base64 decode at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/JSON/WebToken/Crypt/RSA.pm line 19.

When I pull out the private key and try to validate it with openssl, I get a similar error. So is Google giving me a duff key (I've double checked it) or am I doing something else wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use JSON;
use JSON::WebToken;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $private_key_string = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n...\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";

my $time = time;

my $jwt = JSON::WebToken->encode(
    {
        # your service account id here
        iss   => '...9ve@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
        scope => "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/",
        aud   => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
        exp   => $time + 3600,
        iat   => $time,
        # To access the google admin sdk with a service account
        # the service account must act on behalf of an account
        # that has admin privileges on the domain
        # Otherwise the token will be returned but API calls
        # will generate a 403
        prn => 'me@gmail.com',
    },
    $private_key_string,
    'RS256',
    { typ => 'JWT' }
);

# Now post it to google
my $ua       = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $response = $ua->post(
    'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
    {   grant_type => encode_entities('urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer'),
        assertion  => $jwt
    }
);

unless ( $response->is_success() ) {
    die( $response->code, "\n", $response->content, "\n" );
}
```

Comment: I access a Google calendar using the same method, but with a totally different scope: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar`. I doubt that would cause the `bad base64 decode` error, but might cause issues once you get authentication working. You should test all of your parameters at https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ before trying to authenticate with a script. I suspect the real issue is with your private key. How exactly did you extract it from the PKCS 12 archive you downloaded from the developers' console? IIRC, I used the wrong key at first...

Comment: I used the json key, not the PKCS 12 archive. Thanks for the tip about the playground. I had a look at that, but it doesn't seem geared towards service accounts. Still useful to know about.

Comment: It's been a while since I worked on this...I meant to point you to the [calendar API reference](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/), which lets you test different request methods (although it looks like it won't help with the authorization issue). I don't think JSON keys were available when I set up my application (which was only a few months ago). Perhaps try the PKCS 12 route? I extracted the key with this command: `openssl pkcs12 -in foo-privatekey.p12 -nocerts -nodes | openssl rsa > id_rsa`, where `foo-privatekey.p12` is the name of the downloaded archive.

Comment: Also note the following: "The service account flow uses cryptographic signatures to validate authorization. These signatures rely on an accurate computer clock. You should ensure that the time on your server is synchronized to a NTP server and is using the appropriate timezone. If the time is off by even a second or two, you could experience authorization failures."

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. The base64 terminatior at the end of my RSA key had been JSON encoded when I downloaded it from the Google Developer console (\u003d). Just change this to a plain '='.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW service keys are no longer affected by this problem.